# Why is $A$ said to bound a subsurface of $X$ but $B$ doesn't? (picture inside!)

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, soft-question

So i'm completely able to do the question below that relates to the picture in a few different ways. I know that $H_n(X,A) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ since $X$ has a neighborhood that deformation retracts onto $A$, and so we get a wedge product which then breaks up into a direct product of homology groups, right.

Anyway, I also did the problem by looking at the long exact sequence for the pair (X,A) and I have a question...

Just looking at the part of the long exact sequence:

$... \rightarrow H_2(X) \rightarrow H_1(A) \rightarrow^a H_1(X) \rightarrow H_1(X,A) \rightarrow ...$

The map $a$ has image zero because $A$ bounds a subsurface of the space $X$ (a genus 2 oriented surface). However, $B$ does not bound such a subsurface, so in that case things are different. And this is what I need somebody to give me insight, what exactly is going on here? Why does $A$ bound a subsurface but $B$ doesn't? Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: If you cut your manifold along A you get two surfaces with a boundary, namely a copy A. If you do the same with B you get a single surface with duplicated B as its boundary. So single B does not bound anything.

Comment: I’ve never heard this result about submanifolds. Is it in Hatcher?

Comment: Tosun told me that in understanding this part of the LES for $(X,A)$ you need to understand that the image of $a$ is zero for reasons stated above. I mean, I feel like one reason it makes sense that the $im(a)$ is zero is because $A$ isn't homologous to any of the generators for $H_1(X)$... but there is definitely insight that I need in this understanding

Comment: Why is cutting it at $B$ not a surface?

Comment: @ConnorMalin The map $a$ comes from inclusion, and since separating curves (or curves that bound subsurfaces) on a surface are trivial in homology, this map should be $0$.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Cutting $X$ at $B$ is definitely still a surface, but it is a *connected* surface and thus $B$ doesn’t bound a subsurface. You can take this as a definition of what it means to bound a subsurface. Note that when we cut $X$ along $A$ we certainly obtain a *disconnected* surface — we get two tori each with one boundary component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed $1$-manifold $C \subset X$ bounding a subsurface of $X$ means that there is a *subsurface with boundary* $S \subset X$ such that $C = \partial S$. Note that $\partial S$ agrees with the topological boundary $\text{bd}_XS$ of the subspace $S \subset X$

Note that neccesarily $U = X \setminus S$ is a *nonempty* open subset of $X$ (otherwise $\partial S  = \partial X = \emptyset$). Hence $S' = U \cup \partial S = \text{cl}_X U$ is also a subsurface of $X$ which bounds $C$. We have $S \cap S' = C$. Thus $C$ separates $X$ in two submanifolds with boundary $S, S'$ having $C$ as their common boundary and whose interiors are disjoint. In particular, $X \setminus C$ is not connected.

Obviously $A$ bounds a subsurface of $X$ (in fact it bounds the left and the right half of $X$). What about $B$? $X \setminus B$ is connected, therefore it does not bound a subsurface.